# Ruby on Rails Action Cable Not Initiating Websocket connection

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, websocket, actioncable

I am exploring Ruby on Rails Action Cable and wanted to test a basic connection to websocket in the console.log(Javascript) in my Rails 6 version development environment.However looks like the websocket connection is not initiating at all. There are no error messages. When I open the browser console,nothing is displayed. The websocket connection is not being initiated at all.

I generated a channel named as "chat" via the below command. When I connect to `http://<IP-Address>:3000`(The index page is displayed) and open browser console, I see nothing is displayed. As per below console.log, I am expecting to see "connected" in the browser console. Am I missing something?

```
rails g channel chat
```

Here are my file contents:

**app/javascript/channels/chat_channel.js**

```
import consumer from "./consumer"

consumer.subscriptions.create("ChatChannel", {
  connected() {
      console.log("connected");
    // Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server
  },

  disconnected() {
    // Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server
  },

  received(data) {
    // Called when there's incoming data on the websocket for this channel
  }
});
```

**app/channels/chat_channel.rb**

```
class ChatChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
     stream_from "chat_channel"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end
end
```

**Routes file**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'pages/index'
  root 'pages#index'
  mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'
```

**config/cable.yaml file**

```
development:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1

test:
  adapter: test

production:
  adapter: redis
  url: <%= ENV.fetch("REDIS_URL") { "redis://localhost:6379/1" } %>
  channel_prefix: testapp_production
```

**Controller File**

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

Comment: Were you able to solve it I am also facing this exact same issue